# Docker Compose gulp is not found in $PATH

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have just started learning `docker-compose` and I am using a `nodejs` image. I want to install `gulp` to create some tasks and have one of them working on the background.

When I run: `docker-compose run --rm -d server gulp watch-less`

I get this error: `ERROR: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"gulp\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Here are my file:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:6.10.2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "2"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
```

I also have a `.dockerignore` to ignore the `node_modules` folder and the `npm-debug.log`

EDIT:

When I run `docker-compose run --rm server npm install package-name` I don't have any problem and the package is installed.

Comment: Sounds weird, Compose is to run multi container applications. If you want to use Gulp, you may add the necessary instructions to the Dockerfile or use a custom image, volumes etc.

Comment: do you provide the service_name to `docker-compose run` ?

Comment: do you have gulp as dependency in package.json?

Comment: I corrected the command I use for installing packages. In my package.json I have gulp as a dev dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works but maybe is not the best solution. I have created an script that runs a `gulp` task on the `package.json` and if I run:

`docker-compose run --rm server npm run gulp_task` it works and does what it has to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding gulp install in Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:6.10.2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g gulp
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I have `gulp` in my `package.json` and is installed each time I build the image. I tried with `eslint` package but I have the same error.

Comment: But you need them gobally installed if you want to call as `gulp` or `eslint` commands. Try them. As an alternative you will need add to PATH your npm bins dirs

Answer (score 0):

I find that just referencing gulp via

`./node_modules/.bin/gulp`

instead of directly works fine. ./node_modules/.bin isn't in the path by default. Another option would be to add that dir to the PATH.